# why does my jQuery auto-refresh stop working if I add in a if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, partial-page-refresh

```
window.onload = setupRefresh;
function setupRefresh() {
    setInterval("refreshBlock();", 1000);
}

function refreshBlock() {

    $('#activeItems').load("current_auctions.php");

}
```

the above code automatically refreshes the content of a div tag on my page every 1 second.

```
window.onload = setupRefresh;
function setupRefresh() {
    setInterval("refreshBlock();", 1000);
}

function refreshBlock() {
    if ($('#myAccount').html() == 'My Accout') {
        $('#activeItems').load("current_auctions.php");
    };
}
```

The above code, which only has the addition of an if statement, loads up the page once in the beginning, and then ceases to refresh. How can I fix this code?

Comment: Is it because of the typo in the if: `'My Accout'` is missing an 'n'.

Comment: Or condition ($('#myAccount').html() == 'My Accout') must be returning false

Comment: I love both of you sooo much.

Comment: type the answer out so I can check mark correct one =) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because that conditional is returning false.

```
if ($('#myAccount').html() == 'My Accout') {
```

Quite likely because of the typo in 'Accout', as @nnnnn says.

You can debug this quite easily in Chrome or Firefox by using a script terminal. In Firefox you could install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or in Chrome just press Crtl+Shift+J. Either way get to a JavaScript command-line interface and enter:

```
$('#myAccount').html() == 'My Accout'
```

In  your page. You'll see it return either `true` or `false`. If it's `false` you can then easily tweak that condition until it's `true` where you're expecting.

Comment: thanks for the chrome ctrl+shift+j tip. I didn't realize chrome had one like that too, thnx mate!